# Need help on SQL query error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL, need to perform multiple filters in a single table in MS Access 2013. My first step is making copies of the original table, then call the original and new tables for additional commands.

Query:

```
    With test1copy as test1
    select * from test1copy;
```

Error:

```
    Invalid SQL statement; expected 'Delete', 'Insert', 'Procedure', 'Select', or 'Update'.
```

I looked up online examples, not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: MySQL syntax is different than Access. MySQL doesn't use `WITH`.

Comment: does this alias test1copy as test1?  If so you want select * from test1

Answer (score 3):

Just do this `select * from test1;`